# Zoom to text in embeded PDF drawing in MOZILLA

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mozilla

I have an app in PHP/HTML/CSS (and a bite of Javascript) intended for Mozilla.
App architecture is homemade MVC (not relevant) but it is using "nice URL".

There are two pages:

1. Embeded PDF with Technical drawing format A1
2. Table of objects from the drawing

There is a href like `"APP/DRAWING/ID12345"` for each object in the table.
I need to open page with the huge drawing and hundreds of objects and directly zoom to searched object and highlight it (object is represented by searchable text).

Embeded PDF tag with open parameters looks like:

```
<object data="..path/drawing.pdf#search=ID12345&zoom=80" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="850px"></object>
```

What happens is:

1. Zoom is fine
2. Text is highligted

but

3. PDF is not focused on the text, so it is necessary to scroll through the drawing and search for it.

**Am I missing something wrong about the html code, or is it possible to solve this issue in different way?**